# Spring MVC dynamically adding form elements

Tags: java, html, form, controller, spring-mvc

I made a simple form with an option of adding one text field dynamically on mouse click. And I will be grateful for suggestions on how I may improve the code.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

public ArrayList<NewField> fieldArrayList;
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String myForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute NewField newField) {

    fieldArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    fieldArrayList.add(newField);
    model.addAttribute("dataForm", new DataForm());

    return "create";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String formSubmit(Model model, HttpServletRequest hsr, @ModelAttribute DataForm dataForm) {

    if (hsr.getParameterValues("lastField") != null) {


        String[] lastF = null;
        lastF = hsr.getParameterValues("lastField");
        List<String> d = Arrays.asList(lastF);

        int count = d.size() + 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < count+1; i++) {
            NewField newField = new NewField();
            String s1 = hsr.getParameter("p_new_" + String.valueOf(i));
            String s2 = hsr.getParameter("l_" + String.valueOf(i));
            newField.setStr1(s2);
            newField.setStr2(s1);
            fieldArrayList.add(newField);
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("dataForm", dataForm);
    model.addAttribute("fieldArrayList", fieldArrayList);

    return "view";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handing Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${dataForm}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var addDiv = $('#addinput');
            var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;
            $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label> ' + document.getElementById('p_new').value + '</label><input type="text" name="p_new_' + i
                        +'"  /><input type="hidden" value="' + document.getElementById('p_new').value
                        + '" name="l_' + i
                        + '" /><input type="hidden" value="' + i + '" name="lastField" /> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                //alert(i);
                i++;
                return false;
            });
            $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="addinput">
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>
</form>
<input type="text" id="p_new" size="20" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
<input type="button" id="addNew" value="Add New field"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use interface `List` instead of concrete class for the `fieldArrayList`
   field.
2. Make the `fieldArrayList` field private.
3. `@RequestMapping(value="/create", method= RequestMethod.GET)`. Requests using GET should only retrieve data, not create.
4. Extract the calls of `hsr.getParameterValues` and `hsr.getParameter` methods in separate methods.
5. Don't use meaningless variable names such as `d`, `s1`, `s2`.
6. Format code with your IDE. For example, in IDEA you can use the `Ctrl+Alt+L` hotkey.
7. Extract attribute and parameter names in constants.
8. `@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)` can be replaced with `@PostMapping("/create")`.